# How to validate new added field (Phone number) which is added to registration form?

Tags: themes, user-registration

I have added a new field to registration form that is "Phone number" but new field input value could not be saved to the Database and the field value is also could not be added to the user profile. can you help me with the best code snippets or the best way We can do it?

Comment: Share your code, please.

Comment: add_filter(
 'hivepress/v1/forms/user_register',
 function( $form ) {
  $form['fields']['phone'] = [
   'label'    => 'Phone Number',
   'type'     => 'text',
   'required' => true,
   '_order'   => 100,
  ];

  return $form ;
 }
);
                                                                                                                                                            
add_action(
 'hivepress/v1/forms/user_update',
 function update_user_meta( $user_id ) {    
           update_user_meta( $user_id, 'hp_phone', $_POST['hp_phone'] ); 
}
);